# Debug a class declared inside a jsp page

Tags: jsp

In my jsp project there is a page containing a  java class (declared inside the jsp page), now I need to debug the class, for that  comments  and exceptions should be written to the page, I tried out.println("") , out.write("")  but both not working...... please help

Answer (score 1):

I got an alternate  solution,
1) declare a List variable inside the java class for holding the comments and exceptions
2)After function execution completes by access that list  in the page using the object of class 
3)Finally  print values to the page using out.println("").